# How to get the value in RSP register using c++ libcapstone?

Tags: assembly, x86, system-calls, capstone

I'm trying to write a library(call `mylib.so`) using capstone c++ library and `LD_PRELOAD` to find where are the syscall instructions located in a binary(this binary contains some syscall writing in inline assembly), and what syscall are those(i.e. SYS_open, SYS_read, etc).

I use command `LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so <target_program>` to run a binary and do this binary analysis in "runtime" but not statically.

I'm already able to find and disassemble the syscall instructions using `libcapstone`:

```
...
/* pseudo code */
csh handle;
cs_insn *insn;

cs_open(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_64, &handle);
cs_option(handle, CS_OPT_DETAIL, CS_OPT_ON);
cs_disasm_iter(handle, &code, &size, &addr, insn);

/* then get operand information from 'insn->detail->x86.operands' */
```

But the problem is I cannot identify what kind of syscall it is if the value moves into %rax is not an IMM operand. For example, if the disassembled result is:

```
/* result is printed by printf(), the syntax may not be correct */
...
mov rax, 39    --> store value 39 to rax
syscall
```

I can know this syscall is a `getpid()` since `__NR_getpid == 39`. But if the disassembled result is:

```
...
// the assembly syntax here may not correct, capstone returns:
// op[0]->type == X86_OP_REG, op[0]->reg == X86_REG_RAX
// op[1]->type == X86_OP_MEM, op[1]->mem.base == X86_REG_RSP, op[1]->mem.disp == 8
mov rax, 0x8(rsp)    --> store value at address sp+8 to rax
syscall
```

(sorry about the confusion in the assembly code above, I'm still learning assembly)

Here is my thought, please correct me if I'm wrong. I think it should be possible to get the value in this %rsp since the target binray should be already mapped in memory(but not yet running becasue of LD_PRELOAD).

I also assume the value of the `%rsp` in `0x8(%rsp)` above is not the value of "current" stack pointer when my capstone code are executing.

Am I understand correctly? How should I get the address that the RSP register is going to contain during the execution of this `mov %rax, 0x8(%rsp)` instruction?

Big Thanks for any help!

Comment: `mov %rax, 39` would store RAX to memory at absolute address 39.  Did you mean `mov $39, %rax`?  Or did you mean to use Intel syntax, `mov rax, 39`?  Similarly, `mov %rax, 0x8(%rsp)` is *storing* RAX for some reason, not modifying it.  (Unless you're using some mutant hybrid format like `.intel_syntax prefix` with destination on the left but still `%` decorations on register names?  No, `0x8(%rsp)` is an AT&T syntax addressing mode, so it can't be that.

Comment: Re: your actual question, even if you knew the initial ASLRed value of the stack-pointer at `_start`, you couldn't easily know how much stack space would be used during the calls that lead to that `syscall` instruction.  (Except in simple cases like when you can trace the control flow through `main` down a chain of calls, and see what RSP adjustments will happen by then.)  Of course, knowing the address won't help you know what's doing to be in it; stack memory changes depending on the current function.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry about the confusion I made in those assembly codes, I'm pretty new to assembly and still learning. I made some updates and hopefully, it explained your questions.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see... Thank you for your detailed explanation! It seems there's no easy way to get the value in RSP in another stack frame, is this the correct way to say? On the other hand, if resolving the value of RSP doesn't work, do you know if there is any other way to locate and identify syscalls in a binary?

Comment: If they're inlined and intentionally obfuscated, then tracing an actual run with `strace` is the only simple way.  In a normal binary, there will be a `mov $__NR_write, %eax` soon before `syscall` if inlined.  Or much more often, syscalls will only be made from libc wrapper functions.  So you'd look for a `call` to a dynamic-library symbol called `write`, for example.

Comment: Got it. One last question, why there are some of the syscalls in format `mov 24(%esp), %eax` using MEM operand instead of IMM operand? Is there any pattern? Thanks!

Comment: That makes no sense to me, IDK why you'd ever have the call number in memory.  (Unless this was compiled from C that used a really poor inline-`asm()` wrapper with bad constraints, and there's a store-immediate to that same offset relative to the stack pointer soon before that load.)

Comment: Yeah, I was also wondering why there are such cases. I think I need to look deeper into libcapstone and use some test binary to see what really happens, and if I disassembled them correctly. Thanks a lot for your help!